# Tkinter, Canvas refuses to expand or contract when window resized

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I'm trying to make my canvas expand and contract based on window size, with scrollbars as necessary. I have not added the horizontal scrollbars yet, but it scales neither horizontally nor vertically, instead stubbornly remaining at an arbitrary size.

The reason I have 2 frames is because the inner frame scrolls horizontally because I have several canvases which must scroll together, only one of which also scrolls vertically.

```
root = Tk()
maxtick = 1000

frame = ttk.Frame(root)     # , padding="3 3 12 12")
frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

inner_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
inner_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
inner_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
inner_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Primary canvas (inner_frame)
canvas = Canvas(inner_frame, bg='#FFF', width=maxtick,
                scrollregion=(0, 0, maxtick, 16 * (128 + 1 + 1)) )
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

for y in range(1, 128 + 1 + 1):
    canvas.create_line(0, 16 * y - 1, maxtick, 16 * y - 1)

# Vertical scrollbar
vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
vbar.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

# canvas.create_line(10, 10, 200, 50)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure the outer-most grid layout, too.

```
...
root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
...
```

BTW, how about using `pack` with `expand=1, fill=BOTH` .

```
root = Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root)
frame.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

maxtick = 1000

inner_frame = ttk.Frame(frame)
inner_frame.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH, side=LEFT)

# Primary canvas (inner_frame)
canvas = Canvas(inner_frame, bg='#FFF', width=maxtick,
                scrollregion=(0, 0, maxtick, 16 * (128 + 1 + 1)) )
canvas.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

for y in range(1, 128 + 1 + 1):
    canvas.create_line(0, 16 * y - 1, maxtick, 16 * y - 1)

# Vertical scrollbar
vbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
vbar.pack(fill=Y, side=LEFT)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There will be multiple canvas stacked vertically, is pack still suitable?

Comment: @jimbo1qaz: pack is often the best choice if you are stacking widgets vertically or horizontally within a frame. Grid works well too, but it's requires a couple fewer lines of code to use pack.